# appscript htmlservice template query: updating href with data attached to an html template

Tags: php, html, google-apps-script

```
 <?= data["message"] ?>. <br />
                                    <br />
                                    <!-- <?= 
                                    $documentFolder = \".data["documentFolder"].\";
                                    ?> -->
                                    <br>
          <a href=""
```

data["message"] evaluates fine
But I'm having trouble updating the href between the quotes;
I've tried escape characters, building the html element separately but that is not evaluated
any ideas/suggestions welcome

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a little more of your code.  I don't see any scriptlets supporting the href and I don't know what the data source is.

Comment: htmlTemplateBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(template);
  htmlTemplateBody.data = data;

  var emailBody = htmlTemplateBody.evaluate().getContent();   //This is the segment where the template is being built and data is being added.

Comment: <td elq-edit="true" class="em_black_un" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:15px; line-height:22px; color:#2d2d2d;padding:0px">
Hello <?= data["user"] ?>, <br />
<br />
<?= data["message"] ?>.
<br />
<br />
<a id="documentFolder" href="<Linkplaceholder>" style="text-decoration:underline; color:#7d7d7d;">Document Folder</a> 
<br />
<!--This is where the email template is being built -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Building an anchor tag href with templated html

**GS:**

I just made a dialog to test it

```
function myfunk() {
   let t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah1');
   t.data ={url:"https://google.com",label:"Link"};
   let ui = t.evaluate();
   Logger.log(ui);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,'Modeless Dialog');
 }
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
     <a href="<?= data.url ?>" target="_blank"><?=data.label?></a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Dialog:

[image]