# Google Apps Script - issue in Include page template, html evaluate with passed data

Tags: google-apps-script

My code in Code.gs is as below:

`var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("pagename"); html.data = My_Data; return html.evaluate();`

At html side:
I am using an include page for sidebar. I want to set the information passed above in

```
html.data
```

with

```
`<?!= data ?>`
```

so that I can see My_Data but it instead appears as

`<?!= data ?>`

What am I missing here?

**Code.gs**
  `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(res)); var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("myfile); html.data = My_data; return html.evaluate();`

**myfile.html**
`</head> <?!=include('menu') ;?>`

**menu.html**

**Expected output**
My_data

**Actual Outut**
`<?!= data ?>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69960142/7215091

Comment: Hi Cooper, I responded to your solution. But it seems it was deleted by the moderator. I am rephrasing my question - I am trying to use force printing scriptlet inside a file which is then included in another file and hence is being evaluated as text and not a script. This is limiting me to split my included file which is not ideal and prone to errors in future. Let me know if you have been successful in such attempt. I can share the complete if required for further evaluation of the issue.

Comment: It's still there as far as I can see.  The other one was deleted

Comment: Okay. have you tried using a force printing scriptlet inside a file that is included in another file? May be its technically not possible or I am not able to think beyond what I am doing at the moment.

Comment: I don't think I have

Comment: Okay. Thanks anyway. I will do some experiments in free time.